# store file in NSDocumentDirectory of iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using a UIImagePickerController in my application.

After selecting an image by user,

image should be saved at application Documents Directory,

my Code is Give Below.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
     [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]);
     UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
     stuImgView.image = img;
     [img release];

     //write image
     NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", currentStudent.stuNo];
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], imageFilename];
     UIImage *stuImg; 
     BOOL success; 
     NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
     // how to store file at documents dir????
}
```

i dont know how to use file manager to store a file?

Help me Out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For path concatenation, I would recommend using [`stringByAppendingPathComponent:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`writeToFile:atomically:`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:):

```
[imgData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Nope. Something wrong.
Here I need to create a new file named anyNumber.jpg.
NSData won't create a file - image file. (according to me).