# How do I write my files to an NSBundle?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, nsbundle

I am writing an iPhone/iPad app where I have zipped files come in which are basically the contents of a website which I can then run upon extracting.
However I would like to put all these files and folders into a single file i.e. an `NSBundle` file so that I can display it to the user as if it were a single file and where it can then be deleted or moved but not traversed.
(My app allows traversal of folders throughout the `NSDocuments` folder)

I know that you can easily import your own `NSBundle` into your project and then read it into a website.
But is it at all possible to write one using an already made directory structure with files and folders that must remain as they are, i.e. the web folder I described earlier?

If not an `NSBundle`, can I write(convert) a folder into any other type of package?

If not, do you have any other suggestions for my predicament

Comment: You can write to the user's documents directory. See this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256304/store-file-in-nsdocumentdirectory-of-iphone>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative way of looking at your problem.

1. Specifically, you've stated that your app allows traversal of folders throughout NSDocumentDirectory. Since your code is what is enumerating files/folders in there, you could simply implement your enumeration code so that it treats folders matching some pattern (e.g. *.bundle) as leaf nodes in the hierarchy; the user need never know there was anything inside there.
2. Taking that one step further, you could store the .zip files directly in the documents directory, then provide their contents directly to the UIWebView as it requests access to individual URLs.

   It's possible to register a subclass of `NSURLProtocol` which gets first crack at examining all URL requests. If the subclass says it can handle the particular URL (e.g. for a particular host or path), then an instance of the subclass will be created and asked to provide the content.

   At that point, you can use some zip-reading code, for example [Objective-Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) to read the requested file from within the zip, and return its contents back from the request.

   Use `NSURLProtocol +registerClass:` to register the subclass with the system.

   In the following example, my protocol handler ignores all requests, except those to my site. For those it returns the same hard-coded string (as a proof-of-concept):

   **MyURLProtocolRedirector.h**:

   ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @interface MyURLProtocolRedirector : NSURLProtocol
   + (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
   + (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
   - (void)startLoading;
   - (void)stopLoading;
   @end
   ```

   **MyURLProtocolRedirector.m**:

   ```
   #import "MyURLProtocolRedirector.h"

   @implementation MyURLProtocolRedirector

   + (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
     if ([request.URL.host compare:@"martinkenny.com"] == 0) {
       return YES;
     }
     return NO;
   }

   + (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
     return request;
   }

   - (void)startLoading {
     NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:self.request.URL MIMEType:@"text/plain" expectedContentLength:11 textEncodingName:nil];
     [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:"Hello World" length:11]];
     [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
     [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
   }

   - (void)stopLoading {
   }

   @end
   ```

   **SomeViewController.m**:

   ```
   // register the new URL protocol handler with the system
   [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyURLProtocolRedirector class]];

   UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   [webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.seenobjects.org/"]]];
   [self.view addSubview:webView];
   ```

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. With the whole folder renaming thing. Not quite sure what you mean with NSURLProtocol subclass that redirects access to file inside the zip. Are you saying that theres a way to read the zip contents without unzipping to the directory?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was getting at. I'll try and update the answer, later, to be a bit clearer. Basically, though, it's possible to register a handler that gets first crack at URL requests (including http ones) from your app, and gets to supply its own content. You could code that handler to retrieve files directly from inside the zip file.